# Separate CSS for d3.js script

Tags: javascript, css, html, svg, d3.js

I have a HTML document with HTML5 doctype: `<!DOCTYPE html>`, inside which I link a dedicated CSS file for d3.js graphs as well as a separate .js script for drawing the graph using d3.js.

e.g. something like:

```
<head>
    ...
    <link type="text/css" href="./graph.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <div class="graph">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./graph1.js"></script>
    </div>
    ...
</body>
```

Inside `graph1.js`, I set the styles of nodes, edges, etc using classes from `graph.css`.

Now, if I render the HTML file *without* the doctype, the graph is drawn in the browser with the styles from `graph.css`. However, as soon as I add the doctype, it fails to apply any style from the CSS file.

I wonder what is the cause for this problem and how can I fix it without moving the styles from CSS file back to the d3.js code inside `graph1.js`. Thanks!

Comment: What browser are you using? I can't reproduce this error, and all of the d3 examples use `<!DOCTYPE html>`, so there's something more specific at issue here.

Comment: @nrabinowitz, i've tried on both `Safari 5` and `Chrome 21`. Is there a problem with the way I link up HTML, CSS and javascript files?

Comment: I don't think you've included enough code to tell. I would try to replicate this with the simplest possible example code, starting with your code above and a very simple stylesheet and vis. Often that reveals the problem right away; if not, you can post a good example of the issue that others can actually help with.

Comment: Have you tried adding type="text/css" to the link to set the MIME type? Also -- why is your script tag in the middle of a DIV?

Comment: @WPCoder, thanks for the suggestion, I believe I have `text/css` set as shown above; I also moved script element to the bottom of the `<body>`, but still no effect.

Comment: maybe try a very simplified graph.css file? Just the absolute basics. Maybe something is wrong with the CSS file that is causing the syntax to be wrong when the doctype is specified.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Operation Aborted" JavaScript error in IE 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26890842/operation-aborted-javascript-error-in-ie-11)