# "Operation Aborted" JavaScript error in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Using [{track.js}](http://trackjs.com/) I noticed someone using IE 11 generated a ton of "Operation Aborted" errors. This issue was common in IE 7 but was [resolved in IE 8](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927917). Did it come back in IE 11? What could be causing this?

Comment: Maybe it's an issue with track.js reporting? I don't think we have enough information right now to help you.

Answer (score 2):

I realise it has been a long time since you asked, but I just stumbled upon this thread when I was researching the same issue. My feeling is that it's the same error as in earlier versions of IE. Nicely explained here: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2008/03/17/the-dreaded-operation-aborted-error/

> You can fix the problem in several ways:
>
> 1. Move the script element so that it’s a direct child of body.
> 2. Use insertBefore() to insert the div at the beginning of body instead of the end.
> 3. Wait until the page is loaded before attempting to manipulate document.body.

The comment under that post is useful as well:

> Another solution is to add the `defer` attribute to the `script` tag. This will make the script to execute when the DOM is completely loaded.
>
> IE throws this error when you try to manipulate the DOM before its completely loaded.